# Updating number values by year / month with php

Tags: php, date

I was wondering if there is a way to update a certain number value, per year?

Similar to how you would update a website date in the footer like this:

```
<?php echo date("Y"); ?>
```

I'm looking for a way to update a set number each year / month.

Example, say a website says they have been in business for 10 years. Then when the next year passes, I want PHP to automatically update the value to 11 years. Note, that I have to start with the number 10

Another example would be for age: John is 21. After a year passes I want PHP to update the site to say, John is 22.

Or Betty has worked here for 5 months.... After the next month passes it would update to 6, then once it hits 12 months is would change to 1 year then 2 years etc... Thats a little more involved, but you get the idea.

If someone knows how this can be achieved I would appreciate the help, or if you can point me in the right direction to solving this problem that would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to understand two things - the current date and the date you are comparing it to.  You then simply need to compare the too.

I would suggest using the PHP `DateTime`, `DateInterval`, etc. classes which greatly simply this for you.

For example:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$comparison_date = new DateTime('2005-01-01'); // roughly 10 years ago
$interval = $now->diff($comparison_date); // returns DateInterval object
$years_difference = $interval->y;
```

Comment: Thank You, that was the kind of info I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here:
[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

By using strtotime() to convert two dates to unix time and calculate the number of seconds between them then reconvert to human readable.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the difference between to years you can use a simple sum like this:

```
<?php

$cur_year = date("Y");
$year = 2008;
$total_years = $cur_year - $year;

echo ($total_years);

?>
```

For months you could use a similar thing

Answer (score 0):

Substract the initial Unix timestamp with the current timestamp (`time()` returns it), divide by 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, and round accordingly (you will probably want to `floor()` the years an user has been registered, and `ceil()` the years a bussiness have been working)

```
$start = 12345646;
$years = ceil((time() - $start) / 31536000.0); // Important: use a float
```

Note this uses "year" as a set of 365 days. It won't take into account leap years.